# HTML character display problem

Tags: html, spring-mvc

I am trying to display A/c in a div tag, but this label comes from a spring multilingual framework and getting converted into A/C here c getting capitalized, I tried with escape character also but nothing worked

Comment: As trick you can use Russian "с" letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, well your problem is that the browser is capitalizing the letter. Try replacing the 'c' with `&#99;` and if that isn't working check any CSS styles applied to the div for

```
text-transform: capitalize;
```

or

```
text-transform: uppercase;
```

**Capitalize** transforms the first character of each word to uppercase
**Uppercase** transforms all characters to uppercase

And change it to

```
 text-transform: none;
```

==EXAMPLE==
`<div>A/&#99;</div>`

[More Info »](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_text_text-transform.asp)